# Oracle sql query union operation?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. `TableA` and `TableB`. both the tables has some data with two columns as below.

```
TableA
---------
id  Name
--- ----
1   abc
2   def

TableB
---------
id  Name
--- ----
1   xyz
2   pqr
```

Now i would pass list of ids from my application and get same ids along with their names as:

```
select id, name 
from TableA 
where id in(1,2) 
union select id, name 
from TableB 
where id in(1,2);
```

above query gives results as:

```
1   abc
1   xyz
2   def
2   pqr
```

But what i need is if same id is present in both the tables then TableB's Name should be considered but not TableA's name.

```
Expected output:

1   xyz
2   pqr
```

One more is, if TableB does not contain any data then TableA's data should be fetched.

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to use only union or other set operator?

Answer (score 5):

Please try using LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT TableA.ID, 
  NVL(TableB.Name, TableA.Name) Name FROM 
TableA LEFT JOIN TableB 
 ON TableA.ID=TableB.ID
WHERE TableA.ID IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query using simple union you can club the records

```
SELECT id, name from tableA where id not in (SELECT id FROM tableB)
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name from tableB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, name from TableA where id in(1,2) and id not in ( select id from TableB) a  union select id, name from TableB where id in(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT id , name from (
     select id, name from TableA where id in(1,2) 
     union select id, name from TableB where id in(1,2)) t
 GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Union All, and exists/not exists to control which results are returned from table_a based on the existence of any records in table_b

```
 select id,name
 from (
     select id,name
     from   table_b
     union all
     select id,name
     from   table_a
     where  exists (select null from table_b) and
            not exists (
              select null
              from   table_b
              where  table_b.id = table_a.id)
     union all
     select id,name
     from   table_a
     where  not exists (select null from table_b))
 where id in (1,2)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36f26/3

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it if rows can be in A, A+B or B is (if `tablea` always has data, then techdo's answer is better):

```
select id, name
  from (select id, name, row_number() over (partition by id order by rnk) rn
          from (select id, name, 1 rnk from tableb
                union all
                select id, name, 2 rnk from tablea))
 where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (case when B.id = A.id then  b.id else a.id end) as id,
(case when B.id = A.id then  b.name else a.name end) as name
 FROM tableA a left JOIN tableB b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. does this query work if i dont have any data in TableB. if TableB does not contain any data still i need data from TableA

Answer (score 0):

MINUS operator - returns only unique rows returned by the first query but not by the second:

```
WITH tab_a AS
(
SELECT 1 id, 'abc' val FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2, 'def' FROM dual
),
tab_b AS
(
SELECT 1, 'xyz' val FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2, 'pqr' FROM dual
)
-- This is your query --
SELECT * FROM tab_b
MINUS
SELECT * FROM tab_a
/

ID    VAL
----------
1    xyz
2    pqr
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is for selecting data from both the tables(A +B) and then taking out data using minus and join for the rows not required. Code can be easily modified if the requirement changes from selecting names from table A instead of table B.

```
select * from tableA where id in (1,2)
union
select * from tableB where id in (1,4)
minus 
select a,id, a.Name from tableA a join tableB b on a.id = b.id where 
a.id in (1,2);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion