# Performing UNION of two tables oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. `TableA` and `TableB`. both the tables has some data with two columns as below.

```
TableA
---------
id  Name
--- ----
1   abc
2   def

TableB
---------
id  Name
--- ----
1   xyz
2   pqr
```

query:

```
select id, name 
from TableA 
union
select id, name 
from TableB;
```

requirement is: i need the query which would satisfy below the criteria.

1. if TableA has data which is not there in TableB then TableA data must be returned
2. if TableB has data which is not there in TableA then TableB data must be returned
3. if records are found in both the tables with same id then TableB data must be retunrned

How can i write the query?

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: @PM77-1 for records in both tables, it will include `TableA`'s data, where OP wants `TableB`'s data in that case.

Comment: @PM77-1, table B must be preferred when they both match.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question - [Oracle sql query union operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245880/oracle-sql-query-union-operation)?

Comment: Cases (1.) and (2.) are not mutually exclusive.  What should happen if both tables have one identical record and the rest are different?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an outer join instead of a union:

```
select coalesce(TableA.id, TableB.id),
       coalesce(TableB.name, TableA.name)
    from TableA 
    full outer join TableB on
       TableA.id = TableB.id;
```

[`coalesce` selects the first argument from the list that is not null](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php).

Answer (score 2):

Your query does not satisfy (3).

Assuming `id` is not nullable, You could write:

```
SELECT id, name
  FROM tableB
 UNION ALL
SELECT id, name
  FROM tableA a
 WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id
                      FROM tableB);
```

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Btw, you have `FORM` instead of `FROM` in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [id], [Name]
FROM TableB

UNION

SELECT [id], [Name]
FROM TableA
WHERE [id] NOT IN (SELECT [id] FROM [TableB]
```

`UNION` will automatically exclude duplicates. All you need to change is to select from `TableB` first.

EDIT: Sorry, I guess I didn't read your question fully. I've edited my answer based on the comments below.

Comment: Except for the case where the `id` is the same, but the `Name` is not...

Comment: Oops, you're right. I didn't look carefully enough at the data. I''' edit my answer.